# React how to handle add to Cart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, e-commerce, shopping-cart

So I have an e-commerce webpage but for some reason, after adding an item past the first time to a cart it starts to double the value of units in cart as well as double my Toasts. I am wondering what I am doing wrong here. My initial State is 0 for cartItem. Any help will be much appreciated.

here is what I am working with:

Example of cartItem Object:

```
[{
description: "...."
featured: false
id: "6u7pLcaGApuGtiNAf6zLMf"
image: ["//images.ctfassets.net/f1r553pes4gs/17rq7BQ76Q7ouq…010636019e9b3cbc3a10/il_794xN.2378509691_kaep.jpg"]
inCart: false
ingredients: (2) ["Distilled Water", "99.99% Fine Silver Rods"]
price: 20
productName: "Quintessence Colloidal Silver (4 fl oz)"
slug: "quintessence-colloidal-silver-4oz"
units: 9
}]
```

Shorted Version of Code:

```
export class StoreProvider extends Component {
  //Initialized State ready for API Data
  state = {
    products: [],
    featuredProducts: [],
    sortedProducts: [],
    price: 0,
    maxPrice: 0,
    minPrice: 0,
    units: 0,

    loading: true,
    //FIXME CART
    cartItem: []
  }

 handleAddToCart = (e, products) => {
    this.setState(state => {
      const cartItem = state.cartItem;
      let productsAlreadyInCart = false;
      cartItem.forEach(cp => {
        if (cp.id === products.id) {
//Have tried ++
          cp.units+= 1;
          productsAlreadyInCart = true;
          this.successfullCartToast()
        }
      });

      if (!productsAlreadyInCart) {
        cartItem.push({ ...products});
      }
      localStorage.setItem('cartItem', JSON.stringify(cartItem));
      return { cartItem: cartItem };
    });
  }
}

//Button is in seperate component
 <button
    className="btn-primary rounded col-sm-6 col-lg-12 align-self-center ml-1 p-2"
    onClick={(e) => handleAddToCart(e, product)}>
     + Cart
 </button>
```

Comment: Could you share more of your code? Maybe the full component, where you initialize your state.

Comment: I could add more but it's all within a Context so there are 250+ lines in this component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are mutating existing state ***and*** toasting every cart item you check.

## Solution

First search the cart array if item is already contained. If it is already contained then simply map the cart and update the appropriate index, otherwise, append to a shallowly copied cart item array.

Also, `setState` should be a pure function, so don't do side-effects like setting localStorage *inside* the `setState` functional update, instead use the `setState` callback, or preferably, the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle function. Or you can just set localStorage with the same value you're updating state with.

```
handleAddToCart = (e, products) => {
  const itemFoundIndex = this.state.cartItem.findIndex(
    cp => cp.id === products.id
  );

  let cartItem;

  if (itemFoundIndex !== -1) {
    this.successfullCartToast();
    // map cart item array and update item at found index
    cartItem = this.state.cartItem.map((item, i) =>
      i === itemFoundIndex ? { ...item, units: item.units + 1 } : item
    );
  } else {
    // shallow copy into new array, append new item
    cartItem = [...this.state.cartItem, products];
  }

  localStorage.setItem("cartItem", JSON.stringify(cartItem));
  this.setState({ cartItem });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So, cartItem is an Object, looking something like:

`[{'id': 123, 'units': 2}, {'id': 345, 'units': 1}, ...]` ?

One thing to try would be to make a deep copy of the Object, so it doesn't changes while updating:

```
handleAddToCart = (e, products) => {
    this.setState(state => {
      //const cartItem = state.cartItem;
      // make deep copy, so state doesn't change while manipulating:
      const cartItem = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( state.cartItem ));
      let productsAlreadyInCart = false;
      cartItem.forEach(cp => {
        if (cp.id === products.id) {
          //Have tried ++
          cp.units += 1;
          productsAlreadyInCart = true;
          this.successfullCartToast()
        }
      });

      if (!productsAlreadyInCart) {
        cartItem.push({ ...products});
      }
      localStorage.setItem('cartItem', JSON.stringify(cartItem));
      return { cartItem: cartItem };
    });
  }
}
```